# Disabling hover options in Morris Donut chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, morris.js

how to disable hover option in morris donut chart and whenever user moves pointer over chart its value should remain same.

```
var m111 = new Morris.Donut({
    element: 'donut-chart111',
    data: [
      {label: "R", value: ra},
      {label: "C", value: cp},
      {label: "M", value: mp},
      {label: "MA", value: map},
      {label: "A", value: ap}
    ],
    colors: ['#D9534F','#1CAF9A','#428BCA','#5BC0DE','#428BCA']
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can loop through and modify the segment handlers to your liking.

To remove the hover handler (and optionally add a click handler) you could for example do this:

```
var donut = new Morris.Donut({
    // ...
});

for(i = 0; i < donut.segments.length; i++) {
    // Remove hover handlers:
    donut.segments[i].handlers['hover'] = [];

    // If you want select functionality through click:
    donut.segments[i].handlers['click'] = [donut.select];
}
```

See [this JSFiddle demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/L99zmd1k/) of it in action.